# One-way ANOVA table

Tags: self-study, anova

If I am given a one-way ANOVA table, how do I find how many observations are in each treatment and block total ?[image]

I filled the rest of the table and found out the number of blocks which is 7.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.